# How to create RDF containers like list, Bag or sequence using Protege

Tags: rdf, protege, protege4

I need to create RDF container list, Bag or sequence using Protégé.

I also would like to know how we can define a RDF statement and blank nodes in our OWL ontology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protégé is an OWL ontology editor.  OWL can be serialized using RDF, but aside from that, they're completely different.  OWL has no concept of blank node.

You generally can't use RDF container vocabulary in OWL ontologies because the RDF serialization of the OWL ontology may use RDF containers, so it's possible for ambiguities to arise.  But if you want to try, you'd just need to declare the appropriate properties and classes in the ontology (rdf:List,  rdf:first,  rdf:rest rdf:nil,  rdf:Bag, rdf:member,  rdf:_1, rdf:_2, ...) and create the structure you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. If I cannot manipulate RDF files by Protégé, What is the best RDF editor (plugin or IDE for Mac OS)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nasim Software recommendation questions are generally off-topic for Stack Overflow, though you might try the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.  For what it's worth, I usually use the Turtle serialization of RDF (which is plain text) and use emacs to edit it.

Comment: Thanks again for your precious advice. Apparently I was looking for some plugins that can export Turtle format. I am using Protégé 4.0 and 4.3 and also have a look at Protégé 5.0 but it seems to me that cannot represents entities in Turtle format! I hope emacs can help! Thanks.

Comment: I think protégé can export in N3 format (which is a superset of turtle, and most libraries actually are exporting turtle when they say n3).

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this!

Answer (score 1):

Now there is [RDF-Protege](https://github.com/sszuev/rdf-protege/wiki), that is an [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api)-based fork, where this is possible via SPARQL or RDF tree tabs. 
Disclaimers: right now RDF-Protege is a kind of "pet-project" with weak development potential, which has been appeared as an experiment and as a test-stand for ONT-API.